# MySQL, Using indexes with subquery

Tags: mysql

Still trying to learn my way around indexes, shouldn't the JOINs in the outer query be using the index on the Primary Key? Are indexes not working in combination with subqueries? Thanks!

```
SELECT SQL_BIG_RESULT
  I.item_group_id
FROM
(
    SELECT SQL_BIG_RESULT
      MAX(ITM.id) as max_id
    FROM a_movements M
    JOIN a_items_to_movements ITM ON ITM.movement_id = M.id    -- Index used
    WHERE M.warehouse_id IN (...)                              -- Index used
    GROUP BY ITM.item_id
    ORDER BY NULL
) X
JOIN a_items_to_movements ITM ON ITM.id = X.max_id             -- Index not used
JOIN a_movements M ON M.id = ITM.movement_id
    AND M.direction = 0
    AND M.settled IS NOT NULL
JOIN a_items I ON I.id = ITM.item_id                           -- Index not used
GROUP BY I.item_group_id
ORDER BY NULL
```

EDIT: attached EXPLAIN output here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MByU5.jpg

Comment: Please add the explain output (write `explain ` infront of your query). While I am not sure why `ON I.id = ITM.item_id` does not use an index, the first one will depend on the execution order (e.g. if MySQL lists `I` first), and of course on which indexes you actually have.

Comment: Added a link to the EXPLAIN output. If I read this correctly, I see that MySQL expects "1 row" out of the derived table, which is not the case in reality. Perhaps that's why it decides not to use the index. Both <a_items_to_movements> and <a_items> are joined on their PK. Thanks!

Comment: Please add the output as text, not as an image. Anyway, as far as I can see, every join seems to be using an index (although I didn't check if it is using a good one). Only the derived table (the first row in your output) itself doesn't, but since you want to use every row of that derived table, "ALL" is appropriate. You may want to explain why you think it is not using a (correct) index (e.g. "How do I read the explain output?" or "Why it is not using index xxx, but yyy"), or, if that is your intention, "How do I optimize my query?"

Comment: Hmm, thanks! This is my first real dive into the database world and I think I've been absorbing too much information. I suppose I was misled by the 'missing' "Using index" in the Extra column, which I now understand is shown only when data is retrieve from the index, and the index alone, as it happens with a covering index. The other factor that threw me off track is that the query seems to take 100-to-200 ms even though the tables involved barely have 50K each. I suppose that besides adding a covering index on <a_items> and <a_movements> there's not much else to improve.

Comment: Really good job for a first dive into the database world! And yes, a missing "using index" does not mean that it is not using an index, I see how it might be confusing. About optimizing: I didn't check if your indexes (especially the execution order) make sense, also it looks like you could optimize your query logically: your derived query throws away `item_id` and `item_group_id`, and then you do joins to get that information back using max_id. But if optimizing is your goal, you'd need to add more information (e.g. data model, describe what your query should do), and in a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Explaining what I am would take a while. Basically I have items which are moved (in/out) hence the point of the query is to get the last movement, and determine if the item is "in". After which I join with <a_items> which contains the "item_group_id" bit (i.e. the assortment ID), then join with <a_products_variants>, then <a_products>. The end goal is to produce the list of items/products in stock. Will post it in a different question, would love to get the community's take on my gut-inspired approach... :) Loving this place so far, thanks again!